# What are the chances for getting bed head after a week?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Does anyone happen to know an exact or approximate percentage as far as the chances for getting bed head goes? I'm trying to get one of my characters to get bed head, but I'm not having much luck. I know it takes at least a week, but after a few weeks of checking on my character weekly, it's not happened yet.

So is there a certain number of days I can wait where bed head will absolutely have happened? Or, similarly, can I just exit the game without saving and try again? Or will the game recognize that I played on that character recently?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that if you don't play the game for fifteen days, you will get bed head. I haven't proven this statement, so I don't know if it will actually work.  According to the wiki though, it should.

Source: http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bedhead

Comment: yup, according to this : http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Bedhead and happen to my character

Comment: @SabilValdano I have added this source to the user's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that you have to completely not check in for a minimum of two weeks or alternatively you can just skip ahead when Isabelle asks you to confirm the date at the title screen. Keep in mind though, that if you do do that then there will be consequences such as many weeds, cockroaches, some villagers moving out and your popularity decreasing.